# calculate complex integral $\int_{0}^ {\pi} \frac{(x \sin x)dx }{1-2a \cos x+a^2}, a>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration

I don't know how to calculate this complex integral:
$$\int_{0}^ {\pi} \frac{(x  \sin x)dx }{1-2a \cos x+a^2}, a>0$$

Comment: Make it an integral from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, since the function is even. Look for a way to turn this into an integral over unit circle.

Comment: Consider: $a^2 - 2a \cos(x) + 1 = (a + e^{ix})(a + e^{-ix})$

Comment: $$\int_{0}^ {\pi} \frac{x  \sin x }{1-2a \cos x+a^2}dx= 2\pi \ln(1+a)$$